# Get N news for each category

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I need to fetch 5 news for each category in one or in two queries with using DOCTRINE2.

```
      $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->leftJoin('c.news', 'n', 'WITH', 'n LIMIT 5')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```